# Configure XReader shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, application

I would like, if possible, to change the shortcuts to go to next/previous page in the Linux Mint default Document Reader application from Page Up/Page Down (not available on my keyboard) to Left/Right. Is there a specific file I can edit to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Add keyboard bindings](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/issues/174),
you should be able to do it by editing the file
`~/.config/xreader/accels`. 
You have to uncomment and edit the appropriate lines.

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MenuActions/GoPreviousPage" "Left")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/MenuActions/GoNextPage" "Right")
```

should do what you want.

You can prefix the name of the desired key with  or  (for Control key).

Comment: I find the question a little unclear, but it looks like the OP wants to be able to page through their documents with the *Left* and *Right* keys, not Up and Down.

Comment: You are right, I edited the response accordingly.

Comment: This file is overwritten when Xreader is closed.